# Any touch on view crashes it

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, crash, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I have an app a version of which is already on the app store, everything was working but now I am running into an issue where one of my viewControllers is completely non-responsive. Any touch to that view crashes the app with no message printed to the console and "Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" showing in main.m at the int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); line.

The view is brought up like this:

```
#import "ViewName.h"

ViewName *modalc = [[ViewName alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewName" bundle:nil];

modalc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,1025, 1024, 768);
[self.view addSubview:modalc.view];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

modalc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have several buttons on this "ViewName" that comes up, but when I push anything on the screen at all, the NSLog at the beginning of any of my IBActions doesn't even print to the console, the app just immediately crashes on any touch to this view.

The only change I've made recently is I refactored/converted to Objective-C ARC.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: are you touching it with a rock ? have fun :-)

Comment: Check if you have connected view with File Owner.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Instruments with the Zombies instrument.  It should help you pinpoint the specific object(s) causing the issue.  Also check any Clang warnings that may point you to a memory management issue given that you have recently adopted ARC.

Comment: no clang warnings. I've tried following so many Zombies tutorials without understanding how/what they were pinpointing anything. Adding NSZombieEnabled is easy enough, but I never have been able to make use of it in any helpful way...  At this point, I'll probably go back to my pre-ARC snapshot and just leave it without ARC. I don't know why ARC hates this particular piece of code here for adding a view.  =/

Comment: Zombies are quite simple - if you enable zombies, all that happens is that XCode remembers what kind of object an object was before it was released. Then it can tell you something like "UIViewController has no function called buyMeABeer" instead of "Crash in main at 0x67683457823" - which is in  most cases a nice thing to know :-).